# Get category list which gave active posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using this to get category list:

```
$arg = "orderby=count&order=DESC&show_count=1&hierarchical=0&parent=2049";

$cats = get_categories($arg);
```

Now I want to list those categories which have active posts.

I looked at [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) but did not find anything.

Comment: If by "active" posts you mean published posts, then try setting `hide_empty` to 1.

Comment: active means , the post whose expiry date is more than current time . expiry date is the custom field for  a post

Comment: What way is the expiration date stored in the database? Is it stored as a timestamp or in a specific date format?

Comment: expiration date is stored in Y-m-d format